# Как лучше всего подгрузить поля из БД?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Всем дорого времени суток. На сайте есть поля с выпадающим списком, поле используется для того чтобы пользователь мог выбрать нужный ему город в анкете.

```
<select class="row-item-2">
   <option>Город</option>
</select>
```

В базе данных в таблице bd_city есть список городов с такими полями id и name.

К БД сайт подключен

```
require_once 'config.php'; // подключаем скрипт

// подключаемся к серверу
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) 
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

// выполняем операции с базой данных

// закрываем подключение
mysqli_close($link);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне вывести города в выпадающий список?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовал такой метод найденный на просторах интернета. Помогло.

```
<?php
  // Подключение к базе данных MySQL.
  @$on_link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
  if (!$on_link) {
  echo "Ошибка соединения с сервером MySQL!";
  exit;
  }
// изменение набора символов на utf8
  mysqli_set_charset($on_link, "utf8");
// Выбираем БД для работы в MySQL.
  @$db_select = mysqli_select_db ($on_link, $db_base_ref);
    if (!$db_select) {
    echo "Не удалось выбрать БД MySQL.";
    exit;
    }
// Делаем выборку из таблицы.
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `access`";
  $result_select = mysqli_query($on_link, $sql);

    echo "<select name = '1234'>";
    echo "<option value='0'>Выбор</option>";
        while($object = mysqli_fetch_object($result_select)){
  echo "<option value = '$object->id' > $object->name </option>";}
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```